# Maven cannot find main class when trying to run from command line

Tags: java, xml, maven, command-line-interface, pom.xml

I am trying to run a Maven package from the command line, but every time I go to build it, or run it afterwards, I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class utility.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: utility.Main
```

I've searched through multiple SO posts, tried changing things around in pom.xml, but nothing seems to work. It does work from an IDE, but not the CLI.

Here is the build part of my pom.xml:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>        
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>utility.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>     
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Update with requested info:

```java
package utility;

import data.UMLEnvironment;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run();
    }

  public static void run() {
        UMLEnvironment env = new UMLEnvironment();
        Console console = new Console(env);
        console.run();
    }

}
```

And I do see "Main.class" being saved in target/classes/utility. Layout is:

```
src
-main
--java
---utility
----Main.java
----Otherstuff.Java
---data
----MoreStuff.java
---config
----AndALittleMoreStuff.java
```

Edit: I figured out the fix. I was trying to run it via `java -cp target/mmouse-uml-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:target/mmouse-uml-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar utility.Main` when I really just needed to run it like this: `java -cp target/mmouse-uml-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar utility.Main`.

Comment: Please include the source code of `Main.java`, and the project's layout. Does the file have `package utility`? Do you see `Main.class` getting generated?

Comment: What is the fully qualified name of tour `Main` class?

Comment: Updated OP with requested info.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the fix.

I was trying to run it via `java -cp target/mmouse-uml-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:target/mmouse-uml-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar utility.Main` when I really just needed to run it like this: `java -cp target/mmouse-uml-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar utility.Main`.

Comment: If you want to make a single jar with all the dependencies baked in, check out the maven `shade` plugin. I find it easier to work with than the `jar-with-dependencies` when building a single jar

Comment: I'll look into that. Thank you for the advice :)